# how to find the control OfferID?

Tags: asp.net

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
            DataKeyNames="OfferID" GroupItemCount="2" >

       <LayoutTemplate>
           <table runat="server">
               <tr runat="server">
                   <td runat="server">
                       <table ID="groupPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" border="0" style="">
                           <tr ID="groupPlaceholder" runat="server">
                           </tr>
                       </table>
                   </td>
               </tr>
               <tr runat="server">
                   <td runat="server" style="">
                   </td>
               </tr>
           </table>

       </LayoutTemplate>

       <ItemTemplate>
           <td runat="server" style="">

               <div id="wrapper">

        <div id="ResImage">


<div id="slideshow">

    <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval ("Image1") %>' Width="250px" Height="190px" CssClass="active" />
    <asp:Image ID="Image5" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval ("Image2") %>' Width="250px" Height="190px" />
    <asp:Image ID="Image4" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval ("Image3") %>' Width="250px" Height="190px" />


</div>

        </div>
        <div id="ResDesc">
            <asp:Label ID="lblDesc" runat="server" Width="290px" Height="190px" BackColor="White" Text='<%# Eval("Offer") %>'></asp:Label>

        </div>
        <div id="ResPrice1">
            <asp:Label ID="lblValue" runat="server" Text="Value" CssClass="ResValue"></asp:Label>
            <asp:Label ID="lblDiscount" runat="server" Text="Discount" CssClass="ResDiscount"></asp:Label>
            <asp:Label ID="lblYouPay" runat="server" Text="You Pay" CssClass="ResYouPay"></asp:Label>
        <div id="ResPrice2">
            <asp:Label ID="lblValueAmt" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Value") %>' CssClass="ResValueAmt"></asp:Label>
            <asp:Label ID="lblDiscountAmt" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Discount") %>' CssClass="ResDiscountAmt"></asp:Label>
            <asp:Label ID="lblYouPayAmt" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("YouPay") %>' CssClass="ResYouPayAmt"></asp:Label>
        </div>
            <asp:Label ID="lblRestaurantName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("RestaurantName") %>'></asp:Label><br />
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkGetCoupon" runat="server">Get Discount Coupon</asp:LinkButton>
        </div>

        <div id="HowItWorks">
            <asp:Label ID="lblHowItWorks" runat="server" Text="How It Works?" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Small" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label>
            <ul>
            <li><asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="1.Click on the 'Get Discount Coupon' button" Font-Size="10px"></asp:Label></li>
            <li><asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="2.Get a print of your Voucher and carry it during your visit to the outlet." Font-Size="10px"></asp:Label></li>
            <li><asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="3.Show your Voucher and pay the amount directly to the merchant. " Font-Size="10px"></asp:Label></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <asp:Label ID="OfferID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("OfferID") %>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>
        </div>
           </td>
       </ItemTemplate>
```

How to find the label control with the id=OfferID...how to use findcontrol here??
i want to find the OfferID of the row on which i click...i have a linkbutton lnkGetCoupon..when i click on the link button...i want to pass the OfferID in the query string to the next page.

i am a new user so they do not let me post answer to my own question

heres the answer...

i added `CommandArgument='<%# Eval("OfferID") %>` to the link button.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkGetCoupon" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("OfferID") %>' runat="server">Get Discount Coupon</asp:LinkButton>
```

and used the `ListView1_ItemCommand`

```
Protected Sub ListView1_ItemCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListViewCommandEventArgs) Handles ListView1.ItemCommand
        Dim offer As String
        offer = e.CommandArgument.ToString()
        Dim url As String = "~/RestaurantDedicatedPage.aspx?offerID=" + offer
        Response.Redirect(url, True)
    End Sub
```

Comment: At what point, during DataBind?

Comment: Do you need to use `FindControl`? You've already got `OfferID` in the `DataKeyNames` collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the `Label` at all, you can get the OfferID from the `DataKeys` collection.

First, add a CommandName to your LinkButton:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkGetCoupon" runat="server" CommandName="GetCoupon">Get Discount Coupon</asp:LinkButton>
```

Then use it in the ItemCommand handler:

```
protected void ListView1_ItemCommand(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "GetCoupon")
    {
        ListViewDataItem item = (ListViewDataItem)e.Item;
        int index = item.DataItemIndex;
        string offerID = ((ListView)sender).DataKeys[index]["OfferID"].ToString();

        Response.Redirect("yourUrl" + offerID);
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5782665/how-do-i-use-a-photo-slide-show-inside-listview  please check this post??

Comment: @Monodeep: is that related to this question in any way?

Comment: @Monodeep: The comments section is for comments relating to the specific question/answer rather than for asking for assistance with other questions.  I'd suggest updating your jQuery question with your current code and then asking one of the people who provided answers if they could take another look.

Comment: okay..if you are free can you please use teamviewer to check my code??

Answer (score 0):

Attach to the `ListView.ItemCommand` event and within that event you can search on the `Item` in the `ListViewCommandEventArgs` to find the control you need to alter.

Update your `ListView` in your ASPX to hook up the `ItemCommand` event:

```
<asp:ListView ... OnItemDataBound="ListView1_ItemCommand">
    <ItemTemplate>
        ...
        <asp:LinkButton id="lnkGetCoupon" CommandName="View" CommandArgument="<%# Eval("OfferID") %>" />
        ...
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

The `ItemCommand` event will be fired when a Button or `LinkButton` (or some other button-esque control) is clicked. To handle this event, add the following 
code to your *.aspx.cs (code-behind) file:

```
protected void ListView1_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    //Check if the lnkGetCoupon button was clicked.
    if (string.Equals("View", e.CommandName))
    {
        //Get the offerID from the CommandArgument.
        int offerID = int.Parse(e.CommandArgument);

        //Perform your logic using the offerID
    }
}
```

Comment: please explain...i am very new to asp.net.

Comment: i want to find the OfferID of the row on which i click...i have a linkbutton `lnkGetCoupon`..when i click on the link button...i want to pass the OfferID in the query string.

Comment: Yes, now just get rid of the Label. Check my updated answer for more info.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5782665/how-do-i-use-a-photo-slide-show-inside-listview  please check this post??