# Gridview button to redirect with query for row data?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, gridview

Simple question: I have a button field in my gridview, and I want to redirect to an edit page which displays the row data. I think I need to use datakeys for this, but I don't know the steps. How do I place the query into the response.redirect url? The identifying field is SubId.

```
Response.Redirect("~/View.aspx?*whatgoeshere?*");
```

And also, anybody know why despite my horizontal align=right selection (in design mode, so no syntax issue) my gridview insists on left-aligning one of my fields? It's autoformatted to a skin from vs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply you can do like...

```
<ItemTemplate>
 <asp:Button ID="Edit" runat="server" Text="Edit" PostBackUrl='<%# Eval("DataKeyName", "~/View.aspx?Id={0}") %>' />
</ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: @Town; I always prefer simple and smart solution for me and others.

Comment: Yes, me too.  In my defence it _was_ quite late ;)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at my answer to this question: [how to find the control OfferID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5811189/how-to-find-the-control-offerid/5811467#5811467)

It deals with pretty much exactly what you need to do.

Regarding the alignment, I'd recommend posting that as a separate question (with it being a totally unrelated issue) and including your markup.

**EDIT:** As you don't need to do anything other than redirect, I'd do what @Muhammad Akhtar says in his answer.